# JSF propriedade não encontrada (javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable)

Tags: jsf

Estou iniciando uma aplicação em PrimeFaces. Fiz um pequeno projeto que tem apenas uma classe de modelo. Criei uma classe repositório onde coloquei um arraylist dessa classe.

Desenvolvi uma pequena página de CRUD com três funcionalidades: Pesquisa no ArrayList, Exibição do Resultado (DataTable) e Manutenção do objeto (inclusão, alteração, exclusão e consulta).

O Bean gerenciado (ManagedBean, ViewScoped) possui três propriedades: Um nome para pesquisa, o repositório e o objeto acima para o CRUD. Possui métodos de pesquisa, inserção, exclusão, consulta e atualização.

Fazendo o projeto com RichFaces tudo funciona normalmente. Fazendo o projeto com PrimeFaces quando chego na etapa de  Manutenção do objeto dá o erro: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable.

Acredito que seja em função da implementação do CDI na nova versão do JAVAX.FACES. Estou utilizando o Mojarra.

Fiz mais dois testes: Um deles utilizando apenas JSF (sem RichFaces e sem PrimeFaces) e o problema persiste. O outro utilizando MyFaces eu ainda não consegui colocar para executar.

Disponibilizei os quatro projetos publicamente no meu Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3B3_NnGahnyaW5yR1FUeWE0SWM/view?usp=sharing

Se alguém puder me ajuda eu agradeço!

Orlando Dias.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Coloquei CDI e WELD no projeto. Coloquei mais um formulário (h:form) na página.
O projeto projeto  pode ser baixado no meu google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3B3_NnGahnyZGR2alFPdnZCZTA/view?usp=sharing

Obrigado pela ajuda.